# javascript (jQuery) not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed a dragable div with an image inside using jquery. The script is working perfectly in Firefox, chrome but not it IE6. could you please help me to fix this issue

check the web page here : [my web page](http://www.mejoyal.com/jquery/new_drag_style.php)

Thank you very much for your consideration.

Comment: why not just use the jquery ui draggable ?

Comment: sorry, I want to use this script here, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: then please tell us what errors you get, and quote the lines in question, instead of linking to an external site. That is rude and not the purpose of this site. -1

Comment: @Pekka I think milan may be asking for directions to find jQuery UI.  Obviously Googling would work, but nobody else provided a link in their responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably not write the code myself.  jQuery UI provides a `$(...).draggable()` method that should work, and is cross-browser tested.  You can even custom build a jQuery UI download that will only include the components you want.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 3):

IE uses clientX and clientY instead of pageX and pageY. Some people fix this by doing the following:

```
//if IE, then:
if (e.srcElement) {
    e.pageX = oEvent.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    e.pageY = oEvent.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
}

//rest of event handler goes here
```

Comment: He appears to be using jQuery's event object which normalizes the `pageX pageY` properties. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ Although this is the *only* answer that actually attempts to solve the code issue.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you expect a lot of your visitors to use it - just drop IE6 support. Keeping sites IE6 compatible either increases code redundancy or degrades quality.

Comment: but here I want to know the solution

Comment: Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: this is something of a non-answer

Comment: Solve one problem like this and IE6 persists a little longer - causing unnecessary headache to developers - exactly like in this case. I'm sorry Milan, but there's no good reason to waste time on this, and I'm even more sorry that the others can't see it.

Comment: @Dan have you ever had a client, or do you just do work for yourself?  Most developers, in my experience, do not get to dictate what platforms will be supported.  Certainly you can advocate for "No IE6", but suggesting that it can simply be ignored universally strikes me as rather naive.

Answer (score -2):

Since you're already using jQuery, why not use jQuery UI's draggable component?  This way, you don't have to deal with all the mouse down calculations.  I switched your site's code to use jQuery UI's draggable functionality and it was pretty quick and required a lot less code.

Here's the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Drag and drop</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
#dv {
             position: absolute;
             cursor: move;
           }  
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dv").draggable({
            cursor: 'crosshair'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dv" style="position:absolute;left:300px;top:200px;">
<img src="http://www.mejoyal.com/jquery/drupal.png" />
</div>


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: once again, that's not what he asked